# Garbage characters being saved in Payment method input text fields

Tags: magento-1.7

I was playing with one store and noticed some weird behavior.
When I tried to edit the Payment Methods title, it saved as garbage characters. Refer the snapshot.[image: Garbage Payment Method Title]

Garbage characters was saved not only in titles but all the input text fields with some values.

Comment: Never seen this. Did you try a different browser?

Comment: @sonassi Yeah it's happening in all browsers.

Comment: Then go through the debug process and report back. http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/

Comment: Any movement on this? I'm curious as to the solution.

Comment: I am curious about the problem =]

Comment: Is this with the default Saved CC method? It looks like something changed the backend type of this field to encrypted. If that is the case echo Mage::helper('core')->decrypt(GARBAGE); should return the title you entered initially.

Comment: Seems Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Encrypted::_beforeSave() is the culprit file/method. But wondering what makes this trigger only in case of shipping & payment method configuration?

Answer (score 3):

This could also be related to this bug [Magento - Error Saving Configuration - Encrypting](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=14217) The bug is fixed in
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php

```
    /**
     * Get field backend model
     */
    unset( $backendClass ); // Add this line
    if (isset($fieldConfig->backend_model)) {
        $backendClass = $fieldConfig->backend_model;
    }
    if (!isset($backendClass)) {
        $backendClass = 'core/config_data';
    }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm...!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to go through the installed extensions' system.xml files to check if any of them extend payment/ccsave/title and override the default back-end model by adding:

```
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
```

Additionally you can check if this class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data is unmodified. The below code sets the default

```
/**
 * Get field backend model
 */
$backendClass = $fieldConfig->backend_model;
if (!$backendClass) {
    $backendClass = 'core/config_data';
}
```

The same class also dispatches this event model_config_data_save_before which could be used by someone to tinker with the config data.